# Write a regex for number notations

Tags: c#, regex, validation

I created this regular expression:

```regex
^$|^[1-9]+([\.,]\d{0,2})?$
```

It should accept:

```
1
11,00
100,88 (error)
100 (error)
11.00
100.88
```

Shouldn't accept:

```
0
-5
0,55
0.55
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enclose the whole pattern with an optional group and use a `\d` instead of the `[1-9]` and add a `(?!0+)` negative lookahead restriction to exclude matching values with leading zeros:

```
^(?!0+)(?:\d+(?:[.,]\d{0,2})?)?$
 ^^^^^^^^^                   ^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yR9lQ0/1)

If you do not want to match `53.`-like values, you need to replace `{0,2}` with `{1,2}`.

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!0+)` - no zeros at the beginning
- `(?:\d+(?:[.,]\d{0,2})?)?` - optional (one or zero) sequence of:

  - `\d+` - 1 or more digits
  - `(?:[.,]\d{0,2})?` - optional (one or zero) sequence of:

    - `[.,]` - either a `.` or `,`
    - `\d{0,2}` - two, one or zero digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: To disallow zeros only decimal values, you can replace `^(?!0+)` with `^(?!0+(?:[,.]0+)?$)`

Answer (score 1):

So long as the first character is a digit between `1` and `9`, subsequent characters can be any digit.  However, your expression excludes subsequent `0`'s; you need to allow for there to be any number of digits so long as the first character is between `1` and `9`:

```
^$|^[1-9]\d*([\.,]\d{0,2})?$
```

#### Pattern Explanation:

- `^` the beginning of the string
- `[1-9]` any digit except `"0"`
- `\d*` any digit between 0 and unlimited times
- `([\.,]\d{0,2})?`

  - (optionally) either `"."` or `","` followed by between zero and 2 digits
- `$` end of string

See [this](https://regex101.com/r/fU9cB1/1) example for further explanation and unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

From my reading of your question you want the string "(error)" to be a valid suffix. Is that right?  If so:

```
^$|^[1-9]+[0-9]*([\.,]\d{0,2})?( \(error\))?$
```